# In magento 2, how to store observer value in session

Tags: magento2

Example:
I have 2 observer classes. 
1- category.php
2- product.php
I want to store the category.php data in a session variable, like $_SESSION['category']= $data; and call that session in product.php class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class MyOberver implements ObserverInterface
{

protected $checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
   CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
    ) {
       $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }


/**
* @param EventObserver $observer
* @return $this
*/
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{

   $setValue = $this->_checkoutSession->setVar('dit is een sessie test hoppa');
   $getValue = $this->_checkoutSession->getVar();

   return $this;


 }    
}
```